# User registration with confirmation e-mail

Tags: login

I wanted to change the default user registration scenario. My desired workflow is the following:

1.- The user enters in the "create account" form and enters all the user data: username, email, password, reminder question, etc..
2.- Joomla creates the account but the user is not active.
3.- Joomla sends an e-mail to the user e-mail account with a portal link to an url that activates the user
4.- The user makes click on the link and Joomla activates the user

Are there any plugins to achieve this workflow? Any help is appreciated?

Comment: What is the difference to the existing flow?

Answer (score 1):

This will send out an activation email to users once they register that requires a link being clicked to authenticate an account.

1. Click on Users > Manage Users
2. Click the Options button on the top right.
3. Under "New User Account Activation" choose: Self

This is how i have my site configured. Hope it helps